# How can I search my Windows 7 machine for all files with alternate data streams?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, windows-search, file-search, alternate-data-stream

I'm interested to see if any files on my system have any `ADS` (NTFS Alternate Data Stream).

At least the build-in file search on Window 7 Starter doesn't seem to have this option.

Is there a way with standard Win 7 to list all such files? If not what free software should I obtain?

Comment: Software to find all ADS...http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Microsoft/Sysinternals Streams utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) can help you do this easily.

Since `dir /r` displays ADS, something like `dir /r /s | findstr /r "\$"` should also display the names of the files with ADS. If the path is also required, I'm sure dir's output can be chopped up appropriately.

Of course, PowerShell should also be able to do this, but I'm not a PS expert.

Answer (score 1):

Wed 04/07/2021 17:06:27.19 C:\Windows\System32
$ streams -64

streams v1.60 - Reveal NTFS alternate streams.
Copyright (C) 2005-2016 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)

usage: streams [-s] [-d] 
-s     Recurse subdirectories
-d     Delete streams
-nobanner
Do not display the startup banner and copyright message.

Wed 04/07/2021 17:46:25.10 C:\Windows\System32
$